# Vorticity field, rigid body

Tags: rotations

**Derive an expression for the velocity field (u(x,y), v(x,y)) and show
the vorticity 
field is the same at every point (x,y)? .**

When refering to the velocity field , is it refering to the components
of velocity in

the x and y directions that is ($\frac{\partial x}{\partial t},\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$)?. Im slightly confused by the notation (u(x,y),v(x,y))?.

Comment: Yes, it looks like $u$ and $v$ are the components of the velocity in  $x$ and $y$ directions respectively.

Comment: in a fluid, the velocity components(euler) depend on $(x,y)$(where they find themselves) and $t.$